# EC2 Took To Long/Refused the Connection

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

Good afternoon everyone,

I'm here to request assistance on a specific matter. I've been facing difficulties while trying to host a test project on AWS EC2. I followed all the recommended procedures from the tutorials, correctly configured the ports and security groups; however, the project seems to get stuck in an infinite loop during the loading process. In the project's console, I can confirm that the code is executing without errors as all the logs are displaying correctly.

Below, I've included the code responsible for running the server. I'd like to know if there's anything wrong or incompatible that could be causing this issue or if it that i'm doing something wrong on the dashboard.

I sincerely appreciate your attention and support. Any guidance or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

I followed the standard procedure, starting by launching an Ubuntu AWS EC2 instance. Then, I set up the key pairs and configured a security group with Custom TCP port 3000. After that, I installed Node.js on the instance and executed the code.

Here's my server.js structure

```
// Initialize Globals
const globals = require("./globals")

const express = require("express")
const ejs = require("ejs")
const { auth, requiresAuth } = require("express-openid-connect")
const glob = require("glob")
const path = require("path")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const http = require('http')

const database = require("../database");
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = class Server {
  constructor(port) {
    this.app = express();
    this.port = port;
  
    this.app.set("view engine", "ejs");
    this.app.use(express.static("./public"));
    this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
    this.app.set("views", "./src/views");
    this.app.enable('trust proxy')
        

    this.app.use(
      auth({
        authRequired: false,
        auth0Logout: true,
        secret: process.env.SECRET,
        baseURL: process.env.BASEURL,
        clientID: process.env.CLIENTID,
        issuerBaseURL: process.env.ISSUERBASEURL,
        routes: {
          //login: true
        }
      })
    );
    
    this.app.use(function(request, response, next) {
      if (!request.secure) {
        return response.redirect("https://" + request.headers.host + request.url);
      }

      next();
    })

    this.app.use((req, res, next) => { this.handlerMiddleware(req, res, next,this.Schemas) })
    this.startDatabase();
  }

  startServer() {
    this.server = http.createServer(this.app)
    
    this.server.listen(3000, () => {
      this.startWebSocketServer()
      console.log("• WebServer Started!")
    });
  }
  
  startWebSocketServer() {
    const { Server } = require("socket.io")
    const io = new Server(this.server)
    
    this.onlineUsers = {}
    this.onlineRegisteredUsers = {}
    
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
      socket.on("online", async({userId}) => {
        this.onlineUsers[socket.id] = userId
      })
      
      socket.on("disconnect", async() => {
        const userId = this.onlineUsers[socket.id]
        
        if(userId) {
          let user = await this.Schemas.users.get(userId)
          await this.Schemas.users.set(userId, { $set: { online: false } })
        }
        
        delete this.onlineUsers[socket.id]
      })
      
      socket.on("offline", async() => {
        const userId = this.onlineUsers[socket.id]
        
        if(userId) {
          let user = await this.Schemas.users.get(userId)
          await this.Schemas.users.set(userId, { $set: { online: false } })
        }
        
        delete this.onlineUsers[socket.id]
      })
    })
    
    console.log("• WebSocket Server Started!")
  }

  startDatabase() {

  }
  
  registerRouters() {
    glob("./routes/**/*.js", (er, files) => {
      files.forEach((file) => {
        const Router = require(path.resolve(file));
        const router = Router({ requiresAuth: requiresAuth, Schemas: this.Schemas });

        this.app.use(router.dir, router.Router);
      });
    });
    
    this.startServer()
  }
  
  registerTasks(Schemas) {
    const schedule = require("node-schedule")
    const resetTickets = schedule.scheduleJob('0 */12 * * *', async() => {
      console.log("[SERVER || Cron Job] Running 12hr tasks")
      await Schemas.users.updateMany({ $set: {"modules.coliseumTickets": 15} })
    })
    
    const worldBossSwitchOpenState = schedule.scheduleJob('0 */4 * * *', async() => {
      console.log(`[WORLDBOSS] Four hours passed, switching...`)
      const worldBoss = await Schemas.events.worldBoss.findOne({ id: 1 })
      await worldBoss.setRandomEnemy()
      await worldBoss.switchOpenState()
    })
  }
  
  handlerMiddleware(req, res, next, schemas) {
    const URL = req.url.toLowerCase()
    if(URL.includes("/img") || URL.includes("/css") || URL.startsWith("/api") || URL.startsWith("/callback")) return next();
    console.log(`[Handler Middleware] Path: ${URL}`)

    const User = req.oidc?.user
    if(!User) return next()
     
    schemas.users.findOne({ email: User.email }).then(async(user) => {
        if(!user) user = await schemas.users.new({ email: User.email })
        const isUserInBattle = await schemas.battles.findOne({ tamer: user.id })
        const userTutorialLevel = user.newAccount
        
        const whitelist = [1, 4]
        const isUserWhitelisted = whitelist.includes(user.id)
        await this.Schemas.users.set(user.id, { $set: { online: true } })
        
        //var ip = (req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress || '').split(',')[0].trim();
        if(!whitelist.includes(user.id)) return res.render("maintenance")
        
        if(URL.includes("adminbureau") && !isUserWhitelisted) return res.redirect("/")
      
        if(userTutorialLevel !== 0) {
          console.log(`[#${user.id}] ${user.username} - ${req.ip}`)
          await user.updateOne({ $set: {"ip.current": req.ip} })
          if(!user.ip.original) await user.updateOne({ $set: {"ip.original": req.ip} }) 
        }
          
        if(isUserInBattle && isUserInBattle.data.campaignId && URL !== `/battle/campaign/${isUserInBattle.data.stage}`) return res.redirect(`/battle/campaign/${isUserInBattle.data.stage}`)
        if(isUserInBattle && isUserInBattle.data.url && req.url !== isUserInBattle.data.url) return res.redirect(isUserInBattle.data.url)
      
        switch (userTutorialLevel) {
            case 0: {
                if (URL !== '/') return res.redirect('/')
                break
            }
            case 1: {
                if (URL !== '/me') return res.redirect('/me')
                break
            }
            case 2: {
                if (URL !== '/me') return res.redirect('/me')
                break
            }
            default: {
                return next()
                break
            }
        }

        return next()
    })
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect to your app server from another Ec2?
Maybe you are trying to connect by internet and your Ec2 is on private network or maybe you have some network restrictions enable on your account.

Comment: I can't connect from another EC2 aswell, I tried making a new instance with a Hello World code and it went all fine.

Same security group and same key pair, I don't think there is anything wrong with the code because it runs correctly on glitch.